# javascript adding days to date but it show old date month

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am adding 11 days to date started from 19 Feb 2016 and after adding 11 days it become 1st March 2016 but while i run getMonth() javascript function it return feb instead of march

Here is my code

```
var stDate = new Date($("#datepicker1").val()); 
//Fri Feb 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
var secondSeasonDays = stDate.setDate(stDate.getDate() + firstSeasonDays);
//firstSeasonDays = 11
var secondSeasonDays = new Date(secondSeasonDays);
// it return  Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
var secondSeasonDays = secondSeasonDays.getDate();
var secondSeasonMonth = secondSeasonDays.getMonth();
alert("second season start date is " + secondSeasonDays + " and start month is " + secondSeasonMonth );
// it alerts second season start date is 1 and start month is 2
```

whereas date in secondSeasonDaysHere  Variable is Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0500 than why it is returning month as 2 
Any Suggestion would be helpful thanks in advance

Comment: Months are zero based in JavaScript. January is 0, February is 1, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date
>   according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates
>   the first month of the year). The value returned by getMonth() is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April" .. ];
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: so is it fine to add  + 1 like secondSeasonDaysHere.getMonth() + 1

Comment: Yes, if you want to get the decimal value of it. If you want the name of the month, you wouldn't add anything and would do something like `var monthName = months[secondSeasonDaysHere.getMonth()]`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript months starts with 0 to 11.

Use an array as

```
var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
```

Then

```
alert("second season start date is " + secondSeasonDays + " and start month is " + months[secondSeasonMonth] );
```